# Vertically oriented shaft sleeve rubbing against bearing - Calculating side load due to a certain amount of tilt

Tags: mechanical-engineering, solid-mechanics

At some given angle of tilt, we will perceive the pressing of a rotating SS shaft sleeve against a greased bronze journal bearing. How would you compute the side load force on the bottommost bearing if the topmost bearing is cocked/tilted a certain amount (or vice versa) above the angle at which the tolerances permit? We were given what is assumed to be a resultant force from this tilt, but it's unclear how the value was derived so I'd like to do my own calculation to validate or disprove said value.

I was thinking the FLEA formula would be appropriate given that one may easily find the deformation that must result from a given angle, but most applications of the FLEA formula in textbook examples are of a single force applied axially to a beam. In my situation, I believe two identical forces would be experienced in opposite directions at the topmost and the bottommost bearings orthogonal to the axis of the shaft.

F = the value I am solving for
L = I am assuming that the "length" would be the diameter of the shaft given that the force is perpendicular to the axis of the shaft.
E = is a known value
A = I am assuming I must make some estimate based off the size of the bearing itself, but I'm not quite sure what this value would be

Given that the bearing is prohibitively difficult to access, wouldn't any amount of touching/rubbing be unacceptable? I would like to compute some force to determine what kind of force would result from the presumably "acceptable" amount of tilting that was provided. Also please let me know if it seems as if I'm completely off base.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Could you add a sketch of the problem? Also, what is FLEA formula?